# Azure AngularJS Index.html

Tags: angularjs, azure, url-rewriting

My AngularJS app requires all actions to redirect to index.html for processing and it works fine on localhost, but it doesn't work in Azure.
For example:

localhost:1234 -> localhost:1234/#/ works

myapp.com -> myapp.com/#/ doesn't work

myapp.com/index.html -> myapp.com/index.html#/ works

I added:

```
<system.webServer xdt:Transform="Replace">
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="redirect all requests" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

The weird thing is that this works sometimes. I can't for the life of me figure out why sometimes going to myapp.com -> myapp.com/#/ works and other times it doesn't. It seems to also break myapp.com/index.html#/ but only sometimes. This is without making any deployment changes. It just works about half the time.

## Edit

Here is the actual error message:

> Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: What does `->` mean in your question. For instance, does it mean that `myapp.com` should redirect to `myapp.com/#/` or does it mean something else?

Comment: What do you mean when you say, "...going to myapp.com -> myapp.com/#/ works...?"  Where are you going?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that angular should automatically append the /#/

Comment: It's really a bad example...
Just meant localhost:1234 and myapp.com/index.html works but myapp.com doesn't.

Comment: You could try troubleshooting locally by using a hosts file. Have you tried that?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that on azure. The forced redirect works "fine", I just have no idea why the redirect only works half the time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89634/discussion-between-shaun-luttin-and-eccentrikit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be about application startup. Here are some troubleshooting ideas.

**Restart your app.** Does that reliably cause the error?

**Turn on application logging.** [portal.azure.com](http://portal.azure.com) > Browse All > The Site Name > Settings > Diagnostic logs > Application Logging > Level Error. If you want lots of stuff, set level to verbose and turn on web server logging, detailed error messages, and failed request tracing.

**View diagnostics at service control manager** mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net. Choose Debug console > PowerShell. Now you can look through the logs at `home/LogFiles`.

Based on the error you are receiving, it looks like Owin is the problem. Check your websites `bin` to see if there are any Owin references. From the online service control manager, you can try this:

```
cd site/wwwroot/bin
Get-ChildItem -filter *Owin*
```

If there is anything there, then it's probably the cause of the particular error you are receiving.

[image: Online Service Control Manager - Get-ChildItem with Filter]